# sbt run fails whereas sbt package succeeds

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

Please I have a problem running my chisel code. When I do sbt package, I get a success. But when I do sbt run, it fails and I get the following error: 
[Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Zha.png)

I suspected that data is not loaded correctly then the array is not initialized
or I simply forgot to initialize the array, but all the arrays are initialised.

So please my question is what is the correct way to load data in chisel?

This is what I did:

```
val data = io.Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines().map(_.split(",").map(_.toDouble))
                .zipWithIndex
                .map{ case(data, id) => (id.toLong, data)}.toArray
```

Where args is an array of strings defined as such

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {...
```

Looking forward to your responses
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you get an exception when you're trying to access `args(0)` (if that's what on line 24 in main.scala).

When you do just `sbt run` you're not passing any command line arguments to `main`. Add your `args` after `sbt run` like this: `sbt run foo bar`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I was actually not passing an argument so I did sbt "run file.csv" and it worked.